# PHP contact form getting error "missing_mailbox@syntax_error"

Tags: php, syntax

I have included my PHP code and hopefully someone can spot the error! 
I have replaced my email for privacy and spam reasons.

```
<?php
    header('Content-type: application/json');
    $status = array(
        'type'=>'success',
        'message'=>'Thank you for contacting us. We will get back to you as soon as possible. '
    );

    $name = @trim(stripslashes($_POST['name'])); 
    $email = @trim(stripslashes($_POST['email'])); 
    $subject = @trim(stripslashes($_POST['subject'])); 
    $message = @trim(stripslashes($_POST['message'])); 

    $email_from = $email;
    $email_to = 'test@email.com';//replace with your email

    $body = 'Name: ' . $name . "\n\n" . 'Email: ' . $email . "\n\n" . 'Subject: ' . $subject . "\n\n" . 'Message: ' . $message;

    $success = @mail($email_to, $subject, $body, 'From: <'.$email_from.'>');

    echo json_encode($status);
    die;
 ?>
```

Comment: This is side note stuff, but 1) Don't use the `@` to suppress errors/warnings, fix them using `empty()` or `isset()` 2) Use `filter_var($email,FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);` to validate email addresses.

Comment: thanks for the swift response, I'm quite new to PHP you could possibly apply those suggestions to my code so I don't make anymore mistakes :)

Comment: It's not so much a mistake as it's not the best of practices. Here is some logic you can borrow: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32960900/php-contact-form-codes-doesnt-work/32961428#32961428

Comment: Are you sure your POST parameters are ok? Can you print them before sending to check them?

Comment: No I'm not certain they are, sorry for the noob question but how would I go about doing that? thanks so much for taking the time to reply!